# .htaccess rewrite rule mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL:

`http://localhost/sample/custom blog/controllers/sample.php`

and I am trying to rewrite it to look like:

```
http://localhost/sample/custom blog/sample/
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work out.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^custom Blog/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/(.*) $2 [L]
```

This to my knowledge should get me at least like this:

```
http://localhost/sample/custom blog/sample.php
```

Please help me with this.
And also if you could let me know where I can learn the basics of htaccess, I 'll be delighted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in `/sample/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sample/

RewriteRule "^(custom Blog)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/$" $1/controllers/$2.php [L,NC]
```

Make sure there is no .htaccess in `custom Blog/` folder.

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

#### [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)

Comment: Thanks, Still I am getting the 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Ah sorry `$` was missing in my answer, Try it now.